# Retrieve list of all commits associated with a Bug Fix using TFS REST

Tags: rest, api, tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to study TFS REST API, but to no avail it is just hard to understand what parameter is what in the sample request given in the documentation.

What i would ultimately like to do is retrieve a list of all the commits done in lets say a particular project that have a bug associated with them. I want to retrieve a list of all these commits but only the ones associated with a bug fix.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: How did you know if the commits with a bug fix or not in your in company's  process? Have you created some work items to track the bugs? Or you just add some related comment such as `Fixed bug in web.config file` when commit to TFS.

Comment: I assumed that in VSTS when a developer commits a fix, they are supposed to associate that commit with the bug id.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4284627)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version control system  you are using, TFVC or GIT. Assuming you talked about GIT since the commit mentioned in your question.

There is a related REST API to [Get a list of commits](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits#get-a-list-of-commits). For what parameter is what, there are also a detail table with notes. Such as *fromDate* which stands for *Start date to search from*.

- To retrieve the commits with bug fixed comment

To retrieve a list of all the commits in a particular project you could use the **branch** parameter. Usually should fix the bug in a QA branch or DEV branch.

```
GET https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/commits?api-version=3.0-preview&branch=master
```

Then you just need to filter the comment with bug keyword commits.

- To retrieve  the commits related bug workitem

It's more accurate and convenient. First you need to get the bug workitems in your project. Using [Get a list of work items Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#with-specific-fields) with  specific field such as  `"System.WorkItemType": "Bug"`, `"System.TeamProject": "Your project name"`

```
GET https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=297,299,300&fields=System.Id,System.Title,System.WorkItemType,Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork&api-version=1.0
```

When you associate a commit with the bug workitem, TFS will automatically add it as a linked item in workitem specified. Then you just need to get a workitem [with links and attachments](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#with-links-and-attachments-1).

Answer (score 0):

Assume you already have the Bug ID, you can use [Get a WorkItem with links and attachments](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#with-links-and-attachments-1) api to get all the commits associated with the bug.